# Download the file from dropbox?

Tags: php, dropbox

I would like to download a csv file from my dropbox through php to my server.

I tried to use Dropbox API but I cannot get the positive result. I have downloaded the dropbox, installed it on my server and used one of the examples given:

```
<?php

# Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
require_once "dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php";
use \Dropbox as dbx;

$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("app-info.json");
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");

$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();

$authCode = \trim(\readline("the_authentication_code_from_dropbox"));

list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
print "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n";

$f = fopen("working-draft.txt", "w+b");
$fileMetadata = $dbxClient->getFile("/working-draft.txt", $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($fileMetadata);

?>
```

But this code does not retrieve my file :( Any help would be kindly appreciated :)

Comment: You are aware that you do not replace your authendication code with the "the authendication_code_from_dropbox" part, because when readline is enabled, php switches the terminal mode to accept line-buffered input so you must write in the code via a terminal, or replace the entire statement with `$authCode = "the code";` ?

Comment: Also, have you tried using `$accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();` to test that we've got access to the Core API, as recommended in the documentation? And finally, are you sure there exists a file named working-draft.txt in your dropbox?

Comment: No Jonast92, I wasn't aware of that. I'll try that.

Comment: do that, if it works I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: So I did as you recommended but again no luck. I have had an array printed with all allowable file extensions but nothing else happend. and every time I wanted to try again I had to re-enter the auth code.

Comment: When I've put the token myself I had the same result with the information about allowable extensions being printed but no file was downloaded. And the file exists in my dropbox

Comment: Please share your current code (but not the access token!) and explain exactly what's wrong. (E.g. the file is created on the server but it's empty, or the file is not downloaded at all, or you see an error message when you try to download the file, etc.)